# (Fach-)Begriff für "Spaced Repetition"?

Tags: phrase, terminology

Ich übersetze** gerade einen [interaktiven Comic](https://ncase.me/remember/) zur Lernmethode '[Spaced Repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition)'. Eine bekannte Anwendung dieses Prinzips ist die [Lernkartei](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lernkartei) von Leitner.

Eine Beispiel-Verwendung des Begriffs im Englischen:

> Since then, I've used Spaced Repetition to remember all sorts of things...

oder

> Spaced Repetition will fail if your cards feel bloated, disconnected or meaningless.

Leider finde ich keinen deutschen (Fach-)Begriff für 'Spaced Repetition', der sowohl klar umrissen als auch kurz & prägnant ist. Das Perplexe dabei: Die Methode geht auf [Hermann Ebbinghaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Ebbinghaus) zurück, einen Deutschen!

Weil es sich um einen Comic handelt, kann ich den Begriff nicht beliebig umschreiben. Die meisten Sätze sind in deutsch so schon grenzwertig lange, dass ich Sprechblasen vergrössern oder sprachliche Kompromisse tolerieren muss.

**Gibt es einen dt. Fachbegriff für 'Spaced Repetition', abgesehen vom schrecklich langen 'Wiederholungen in regelmäßigen Abständen'?**

** unentgeltlich, [sollte das jemanden beruhigen](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/sollten-wir-%c3%9cbersetzungsfragen-von-software-programmieren-beantworten)

Comment: Gib doch bitte noch einen konkreten Kontext dazu an, also ein, zwei Sätze, wo der Begriff bei dir konkret vorkommen soll. Das würde sehr dabei helfen, den richtigen Begriff zu finden.

Comment: Hier noch ein kritischer Einwand: Könnte das in einem "normalen" Deutsch  nicht einfach die gute alte *Wiederholung* sein, oder zur Not noch die *regelmäßige Wiederholung* oder *laufende Wiederholung*? Das Konzept der Wiederholung (beim Lernen) schließt ja von vornherein ein, dass diese Wiederholung ***in Abständen*** erfolgt. Wenn sie ununterbrochen erfolgt, ist es einfach keine sinnvolle Wiederholung (eher schon eine Form von Autismus). Könnte es sein, dass *Spaced repetition* vor allem Wortgeklingel ist?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Kontext hinzugefügt. Zum "Wortgeklingel": Auch wenn sich nicht alle über die Details einig sind: Der Fokus liegt genau auf der "richtigen" Wahl der Abstände.

Comment: Doch du kannst meinem Einwand, dass repetitives Lernen dieser Art *per se* eine sinnvolle Abstandswahl voraussetzt, und dass es daher tautologisch wäre, dies noch extra zu erwähnen, nichts abgewinnen?

Answer (score 2):

Der am häufigsten genutzte deutsche Begriff für "Spaced Repetition" ist anscheinend die

> verteilte Wiederholung

wie etwa hier erläutert

> ... wir stellen Ihnen das System der verteilten Wiederholung oder die Methode der Wiederholungsintervalle (Spaced Repetition System oder SRS auf Englisch) vor, auf welchem die [...]-Apps zum effizienten Lernen von Wörtern und Sätzen einer Fremdsprache basieren.

[Quelle](https://www.mosalingua.com/de/system-der-wiederholungsintervalle-sich-etwas-merken-und-nie-mehr-vergessen/)

oder

> Die Spaced Repetition heißt auf deutsch „verteilte Wiederholung“. Der
>   Name sagt schon viel über die Technik aus. Denn du teilst dir dabei
>   den Stoff, den du wiederholen willst, in mehrere Intervallen auf.

[Quelle](https://brainbold.de/2018/02/26/spaced-repetition/)

Comment: Bitte poste Links nur um die Quelle eines Zitats zu nennen, nicht als Ersatz für den zu zitierenden Text selbst. In 10 Jahren wird deine Antwort aller Voraussicht nach noch immer online sein, während das auf die verlinkten Seiten nur in seltenen Fällen zutrifft. Du riskierst, dass deine Antwort als »very low quality, link only« markiert und dann gelöscht wird.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast   ... eher meistens schon nach zwei Jahren...

Comment: @HubertSchölnast danke für den Hinweis und die Kritik, auch wenn ich diese nur eingeschränkt nachvollziehen kann habe ich die Antwort abgeändert ;)

Comment: @mtwde  Vielleicht hilft es Dir, das Problem zu verstehen, wenn wir es hier in sinnvollem Abstand noch einmal erläutern? Internet-Links verlieren überraschend schnell ihre Gültigkeit (meistens, weil irgend jemand am System herumschraubt, um es technisch aktuell zu halten; manchmal weil die Website einfach eingestellt wird), und dann wären deine sorgfältig verlinkten Erläuterungen perdu. Dieses Forum hier setzt aber darauf, dass es auch nach etlichen Jahren noch lesbar ist.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Das Prinzip des "link decay/link rot" ist mir bewusst und da stimme ich auch überein. Ich sah es halt nicht als "link only"-Antwort, auch wenn man über so etwas [diskutieren kann](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Selbst mit nicht-funktionierenden Links wäre die "Antwort auf die eigentliche Frage" noch immer da gewesen. Nur eben nicht mehr belegt, was aber immer und mit jeder durch Links belegten Antwort passieren kann. Wobei zugegeben nun etwas mehr "Fleisch" an der Antwort ist.

Comment: Genau das ist ja der Sinn der Vorgaben: Dass man die Essenz der verlinkten Artikel direkt in die Antwort editiert, und so die Grundlage für die Korrektheit der Antwort eben auch noch hat, wenn die verlinkte Seite nicht mehr existiert.